504 Gateway Timeout in Production for Django API Endpoint with Meta Products Feed API, but Works Locally
I'm working on a Django API that integrates with the Meta API for WhatsApp product feeds. This endpoint works perfectly on my local machine, but when I deploy it to production, it returns a 504 Gateway Timeout error.
Details:
Local Request (Works):
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/whatseat/save-changes/ -d "business_id=2"
Production Request (504 Gateway Timeout):
curl -X POST https://<production-url>/api/whatseat/save-changes/ -H "Authorization: Token <token>" -d '{"business_id": 2}'
Key Observations:

Error happens only in production—locally, the endpoint works fine.
When this endpoint is called without the necessary WhatsApp data, it correctly returns a prompt to complete settings. So, the problem seems to occur during an external API request to the Meta (WhatsApp) API.

 def post(self, request):
    business_id = request.data.get('business_id')
    
    try:
        whatsapp_business = WhatsApp.objects.get(business=business_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return Response({"message": "Complete WhatsApp setup in settings"}, status=400)
    
    access_token = whatsapp_business.access_token
    product_catalog_id = whatsapp_business.catalog_id
    
    if not all([access_token, product_catalog_id]):
        return Response({"error": "Missing Access Token or Catalog ID"}, status=400)

    # External API request (seems to be the timeout issue in production)
    try:
        product_feed_data = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('get-product-feeds'))
        response = requests.get(product_feed_data, params={
            'access_token': access_token,
            'product_catalog_id': product_catalog_id
        })
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=500)

    # Other logic...
(contains another call to graph api for uploading the new data feed)

Troubleshooting Attempts:

Local vs. Production Testing: Locally, the endpoint works without issues.

Error Isolation: Confirmed the timeout is likely due to the Meta Products Feed API request.


What might cause a 504 Gateway Timeout when accessing the Meta Products Feed API in production, but not locally? Could this be due to server or network configuration differences, or specific Meta API requirements in production? Any advice on addressing API timeouts in Django would be helpful.

Sounds like your production server was probably not making the request to the API directly, but some sort of proxy server is involved.
